# Keep removing latest historical commit git

Tags: git, commit, git-commit

How do we remove (n) latest historical commit(s) git

after going to new branch:

```
$ git checkout -b simple-string 5e020716
```

then it needs to keep on eliminating latest commits after checking it out, ensure that it's worthless till get the worthy one to keep

How to do such git in sense that really just that nothing else, as it's only for keeping historically a record on certain commits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to keep making exploratory changes is to keep making branches and trying them out.

Your example is a fine way to proceed. Let's say we know that 5e0207 was good and now we are trying to decide what to do next:

```
$ git checkout -b tryThisWay 5e020716
# develop, develop, develop...
# oh darn
$ git checkout -b tryAnotherWay 5e020716
# develop, develop, develop...
# oh darn
$ git checkout -b tryAThirdWay 5e020716
# develop, develop, develop...
# aha!
```

So now you can delete `tryThisWay` and `tryAnotherWay`.

Another possibility is to keep resetting, but that is riskier because what if you change your mind? So you could go:

```
$ git checkout -b tryThisWay 5e020716
# develop, develop, develop...
# oh darn
$ git reset --hard 5e020716
# develop, develop, develop...
# oh darn
$ git reset --hard 5e020716
# develop, develop, develop...
# aha!
```

But why do that? Branches are cheap, and hard resets are violent.